# transform_iterator not compatible with std::iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm having problems using `boost::transform_iterator`s where "ordinary" iterators are expected. For instance, I want to add all keys from a map to a set. I wrote the following short snippet:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
struct map_keys {
    typedef const K& result_type;
    const K& operator()(const std::pair<K,V>& kvp) const {
        return kvp.first;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, double> my_map;
    std::set<int> my_set;
    my_map[1]=1.2;
    my_map[2]=2.4;
    my_map[4]=4.1;
    my_map[6]=12.2;
    my_map[123]=3;
    typedef map_keys<int, double> mk;
    auto b = boost::make_transform_iterator(my_map.begin(), mk()),
        e = boost::make_transform_iterator(my_map.end(), mk());
    my_set.insert(b,e);
    return 0;
}
```

After the `insert`, `my_set` contains a single value, `-858993460` or `0xcccccccc`. Why? If I print `*b` in a loop, all the values are printed as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself suddenly. The problem is the typedef `result_type` (which is not mentioned in the documentation, but unless I have it, the code does not compile (`result_type` is not a member of `map_keys<K,V>`)). If I instead typedef it as

```
typedef K result_type;
```

It works. I suppose as it was written earlier, it returned the address of something?

Comment: It returned a reference to argument `kvp`. That is a reference itself, and probably to a temporary. BTW, `result_type` _is_ documented, under `boost::result_of`, and `transform_iterator` is documented as using `result_of`.

Comment: @MSalters: Hm, ok. I searched the document for `result_type` and it came up blank. But knowing what to look for, it's there. I'm finding reading boost docs quite hard, there are so many templates all over the place you hardly see the forest for all the trees... Anyways, thanks for the clarification!